# ul>li>a padding top/bottom

Tags: css

Пытался задать padding ссылке в списке, но работает только правый и левый.
Верхний и нижний тоже задаётся, но ссылка не растягивает при этом высоту li.

Вот наглядный пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался создавать пустой index.html, куда помещал только это меню, без каких либо подключенных стилей, вертикальные padding так же игнорировались.

Есть ли способ решить или обойти эту проблему? line-height не подойдёт, т.к. есть кнопки, которые не влазят в 1 строку.

Comment: Наглядным примером, должен быть воспроизводимый пример, а не картинка...

Comment: А заголовок вопроса должен содержать суть вопроса...

Comment: Ну давай я сейчас буду вылизывать этот вопрос до идеальнейшего оформления, по всем канонам сайта, только чтобы угодить тебе :)
Никогда не понимал замечания людей, вроде тебя, какой смысл? Всем плевать. Кто сможет помочь - тот поймёт и поможет. Какая к чёрту разница?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что `a` - строчный элемент. Padding на самом деле работает, но не выбивает их из строки. Вот:

```css
ul > li:nth-child(1) > a {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
ul > li:nth-child(2) > a {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>Тест</a></li>
  <li><a>Тест</a></li>
</ul>
```

Проблема решается, если добавить им, например, `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score -1):

Потому что `padding` надо задавать для `li`. Или задать `margin` для `a`

Comment: Margin для `a` так же игнорируется. Т.к. в этом меню мне нужно оперировать с `background` в ссылках, при применении padding к `li` ,`background` отражался не так, как мне нужно. Прибегать к `width:calc()` и задавать отрицательные `margin` я большим желанием не горел, т.к. это отвратительная верстка. Собственно, поэтому я и обратился сюда.

Comment: Это надо было написать в вопросе.